# Exclude folders from TFS unittest coverage

Tags: c#, code-coverage

Can we customize the unit test coverage figuring way in TFS

We are running Continuous Integration in our team. the key is unittest.
we check in code in TFS, and will trig a build, only reach a certain unittest coverage ratio, say, 50%, our check in can be done.

Now we are struggling for a target, 50% of coverage rate.

The problem now is, a lot of our code is auto generated by XSDObjGen.exe
for this sort of codes, we place them in a specific folder named XSDObjGen.

I am thinking how to customize the UT coverage figuring method of TFS, let TFS NOT take the codes in XSDObjGen folder into account when calculating the coverage ratio.

Can you help to give some tips?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full explanation on that topic:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx

Using the attribute [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] solved my problems.

Comment: please close this question